# Searching for an exact values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, search

I have a Dictionary and I want to search for the keys which correspond to a particular value I need (`S009` and `S007` in this case)

I wrote the following code but I get nothing from it

Here is my Code:

```
def find():
    L = [{"V": "S001"},
         {"V": "S002"},
         {"V": "S001"},
         {"V": "S001"},
         {"V": "S001"},
         {"V1": "S002"},
         {"V111": "S005"},
         {"V2": "S005"},
         {"V":  "S009"},
         {"V3": "S007"}]

    L1 = []
    for y in range (len(L)) :
        for j in L[y].values():
            L1.append(j)

    L2=[]
    for z in L1:
        if z not in L2:
            L2.append(z)

    count =0
    l3=[]
    s = set(L1)
    for z in L2:
        for y in L1:
           if z in L2:
               count =count +1

           if count == 2:
               l3.append(z)

    for s in l3:
        print(s)

def main():
    find()
    main()
```

**My code explained:** First, I took all the values in a list and called it `L1`. Then I get all the values without being copied in `L2`. Then, I want to search if an element of `L2` exists in `L1`. After this loop, if the `count` became only one so this is the value I'm looking for & I append it to an empty list called `l3`

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: This was the most horrifying edit I have ever done. Please format your question and code before posting it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps. First extract all the values from L:

```
values = []
for i in L:
    for v in i.values():
        values.append(v)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
values = [v for i in L for v in i.values()]
```

Then filter out the items with count more than 1:

```
result = [i for i in values if values.count(i) == 1]
print (result)
```

Result:

```
['S009', 'S007']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've defined above as `L` is a list of individual dictionaries. I'm not sure this is what was intended. You said you're expected output should be `'s009'` and `'s007'`, so I'm going to assume that, perhaps, you intended L to just be a list of the values of each individual dictionary. In that's the case,

```
L = ["S001", "S002", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S002", "S005", "S005", "S009", "S007"]
```

One of the easiest ways to count the number of items of a list is to use a `Counter` from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module.

Then just create the `Counter` with the `L` as the only argument

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(L)
print(c)
Counter({'S001': 4, 'S002': 2, 'S005': 2, 'S009': 1, 'S007': 1})
```

Now you can see how many instances of each element of `L` exist. From there you can just use a little list comprehension to filter out anything that doesn't have one instance.

```
result = [key for key, value in c.items() if value == 1]
print(result)
['S009', 'S007']
```

All the code:

```
from collections import Counter

L = ["S001", "S002", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S002", "S005", "S005", "S009", "S007"]
c = Counter(L)

result = [key for key, value in c.items() if value == 1]
```